# Visual Studio - migrating to new layout

Tags: visual-studio-2012, razor

I've built an application which uses the default layout, _Layout.cshtml in the Shared folder. This application has at least 100 views, and I want to start migrating it to a new layout. How can I do this without just getting rid of _Layout.cshtml? I want the other views to use _Layout.cshtml for now and just have my home page (index.cshtml in Home folder) to have the new layout.

I've referenced the style sheet in my home page but both the default shared style and the new style are being applied which looks awful.

Comment: other different ways to change layout on page is shown here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510465/how-to-switch-layout-view-in-mvc5/25510977#25510977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case if you just want to implement a new layout only on `Index` Page then just include `Layout` `explicitely` in `Index.cshtml` Page as shown :

```
@{
   Viewbag.Title = "Index";
   Layout = "// Give Path of new layout here //";
}
```